# How to make javascript and css dynamic?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dynamic

I am including header.php and footer.php in each of my page and I am loading the remaining contents of each page via ajax. My jquery codes are at footer.php. Now on initial load everything seems fine but whenever I navigate to the next page the jquery codes are not working. They do work if I include them in the body of each page but that however increases page load time. Also I donot need all the jquery for one page. How to call jquery dynamically according to page url?

Comment: when you navigate to next page, jQuery codes are not working, what are they ?? slider, click events ??

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery [.on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/) to define click events :

ex :

```
$(document).on( eventName, selector, function(){ } );
```

or

define Click Events in the html, you get from ajax.